# How to close SoftInputKeyboard before alert dialog dismiss

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText inside alertDialog. When i click outside the alertDialog , It closes . But the Keyboard doesn't get dismissed. I have focus change listener set to Edit text where i am checking if edittext doesn't have focus, close the keyboard.

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            setClearIconVisible(isNotEmpty(getText()));
            mInputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } else {
            setClearIconVisible(false);
            mInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

But when i tap outside the dialog to close it. The code in else part of onFocusChange doesn't even hit. Can someone Help?

Answer (score -1):

you can set onCancel listener when dialog is cancel out

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // hide softkeyboard
    }
})
```

Comment: I did try doing that . onCancel , I am doing mEditText.clearFocus().   Which in turn calls mInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getWindowToken(), 0). But i think since editText is not visible once alertDialog dismisses , hence this doesn't hide the keyboard

Comment: Hiding keyboard is rather tricky. What method you use to hide keyboard? Does this help? - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/cf4da9f2e0fa1b1d329d3f72d727696b